# How to configure mongodb via jndi in Jboss 4/5/6 versions?

Tags: mongodb, jboss, jndi

How can i configure mongodb via jndi in JBOSS versions 4/5/6??

for example we can configure JNDI related propeties in Context.xml of tomcat i would like to know where can it be done in JBOSS. I am new to JBoss.

Sorry for the bad english.

Thanks in advance